# Having trouble making memset function?

Tags: c, memset

```
void memSet(char destination[], char valueMemSet, int numOfValue)
{

    char temp;
    int j=1;

    for (int i = 0; i <= numOfValue; i++)
    {

        temp = destination[i];
        destination[i] = valueMemSet;
        destination[j] = temp;
        j++;


    }

}
```

The array is originally "this is the source Concatenate means to link."

This is what I am trying to get  "------this is the source Concatenate means to link."

This is What I am currently getting "-------Tthe source Concatenate means to link."

When I ran the debugger it saves the first letter of the array but every single one after gets replaced.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Do you understand the actual `memset()` does not do concatenation? Why confuse people?

Comment: I'm not trying to do concatenation. That is just what it says in the array. I'm trying to make my own memset function that just adds 6 '_' to the front .

Comment: Your `<=` should be `<`

Comment: @SouravGhosh Sorry about that I had to tabs open one for memset() and the other for strcat() and thought memset() did both of those. Once again I am sorry about that.

Comment: Some of the problems in your code: you can't 'move' the existing data from the front since as you place the data in it's new position you'll destroy the data that was there (and hasn't been moved yet).  You need to move the existing data starting from the end.  You also need to make sure that `destination` has enough memory to accommodate being grown. I'll bet that it doesn't.  As @SouravGhosh mentions, you should name this function something other than `memset()` or `strcat()` since those names already have a common meaning that is different than what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

`memset()` is a function, which sets a particular value in a given memory, like you want to initialize total array's elements to some particular value(for eg - zero). So it will set the same in that array.

what you need here is `strcat()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you need?

```
void memSet(char destination[], char valueMemSet, int numOfValue, int len)
{
    int j=len-numOfValue;

    for (int i = len-1;i>=numOfValue;i--) { 
         destinstion[i] = destination[j--];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfValue; i++)
    {
        destination[i] = valueMemSet;
    }
}
```